# Visual Studio 2019 Always Rebuilds, Doesn't Make Changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

As the title says, VS 2019 is rebuilding regardless of changes, and isn't actually compiling a new version of my dll unless I delete the old dll.
I've tried deleting the bin, obj, and .vs files, as well as simply moving all of the files and creating an entirely new project with the same files, with no luck. I also updated to the latest version. It has no statement on whether or not the project is "up to date" (or ctrl-f isn't finding one in the build output.) The only things I remember changing were just some lines in one of the cs files. This is what I get for not setting up the project on github :(

I attempted to paste the "verbose" build output into hastebin, pastie.io and pastebin, and it was too big :/

If there's something else you need, reply saying what it is and I'll supply it. If there's something you'd like me to find in the build log, or if you'd like me to upload the build log somewhere, I can do that to.

EDIT:
I have the 'verbose' log, it is lacking the 'out of date' message explaining why the rebuild is necessary.
It is a singular project dependent on nothing else.

Comment: How is your project structured? Is the DLL the only project or is it being referenced by another project? If it's being referenced by another project, how is it referenced?

Comment: Increase log verbosity? (eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/msbuild-logs?view=vs-2019#incremental-build-is-building-more-than-it-should)

Answer (score 0):

In true Visual Studio fashion, the problem fixed itself. I've included the troubleshooting steps I took in hopes they may help someone with a similar issue.

Delete the '.vs' folder
Delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders.
Readd project references.
Create a new project with the same files.

To be clear none of these solved the issue. It still built every time, outputting '1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up to date' at the end, while not actually replacing the old dll. As a workaround, I manually deleted the dll before every build, which caused it re-build it correctly. Eventually, it just stopped having the issue. I would assume whatever lines of code I added that caused the issue were removed/edited.